# How to increment a specific key in a list of dictionaries based on the values of other keys in Python

Tags: python

I have the following list of dictionaries

```
my_list = [
{'id': 0, 'au_type': 1, 'sequence_id': 0, 'AU_start_position': 0},
{'id': 0, 'au_type': 1, 'sequence_id': 0, 'AU_start_position': 4095}, 
{'id': 0, 'au_type': 1, 'sequence_id': 0, 'AU_start_position': 8092},
{'id': 0, 'au_type': 3, 'sequence_id': 0, 'AU_start_position': 5678},    
{'id': 0, 'au_type': 1, 'sequence_id': 1, 'AU_start_position': 13525}, 
{'id': 0, 'au_type': 1, 'sequence_id': 1, 'AU_start_position': 13587}, 
{'id': 0, 'au_type': 1, 'sequence_id': 1, 'AU_start_position': 14576},
{'id': 0, 'au_type': 3, 'sequence_id': 1, 'AU_start_position': 15019}, 
{'id': 0, 'au_type': 3, 'sequence_id': 1, 'AU_start_position': 15560}, 
{'id': 0, 'au_type': 3, 'sequence_id': 1, 'AU_start_position': 16004}
 ]
```

I'm looking for a way to edit the value of 'id' (that now is always 0) for elements with the same `'au_type'` and `'sequence_id'`.
`'id'` shall be incremented by one for different value of `'AU_start_position'`.
So, based on my_list above, my goal is to get the following list:

```
my_new_list = [
{'id': 0, 'au_type': 1, 'sequence_id': 0, 'AU_start_position': 0},
{'id': 1, 'au_type': 1, 'sequence_id': 0, 'AU_start_position': 4095}, 
{'id': 2, 'au_type': 1, 'sequence_id': 0, 'AU_start_position': 8092},
{'id': 0, 'au_type': 3, 'sequence_id': 0, 'AU_start_position': 5678},    
{'id': 0, 'au_type': 1, 'sequence_id': 1, 'AU_start_position': 13525}, 
{'id': 1, 'au_type': 1, 'sequence_id': 1, 'AU_start_position': 13587}, 
{'id': 2, 'au_type': 1, 'sequence_id': 1, 'AU_start_position': 14576},
{'id': 0, 'au_type': 3, 'sequence_id': 1, 'AU_start_position': 15019}, 
{'id': 1, 'au_type': 3, 'sequence_id': 1, 'AU_start_position': 15560}, 
{'id': 2, 'au_type': 3, 'sequence_id': 1, 'AU_start_position': 16004}     ]
```

Thank you for any hints you can provide

Comment: Could you elaborate on what kind of problem you are trying to solve? There may be a better way to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `iterrools.groupby` to group all dicts with same `au_type` and `sequence_id` and then update the `id` of each dict

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> res = [dict(d, id=i) for _,grp in groupby(my_list, key=lambda d: (d['au_type'],d['sequence_id'])) for i,d in enumerate(grp)]
>>>
>>> print (*res, sep='\n')
{'id': 0, 'au_type': 1, 'sequence_id': 0, 'AU_start_position': 0}
{'id': 1, 'au_type': 1, 'sequence_id': 0, 'AU_start_position': 4095}
{'id': 2, 'au_type': 1, 'sequence_id': 0, 'AU_start_position': 8092}
{'id': 0, 'au_type': 3, 'sequence_id': 0, 'AU_start_position': 5678}
{'id': 0, 'au_type': 1, 'sequence_id': 1, 'AU_start_position': 13525}
{'id': 1, 'au_type': 1, 'sequence_id': 1, 'AU_start_position': 13587}
{'id': 2, 'au_type': 1, 'sequence_id': 1, 'AU_start_position': 14576}
{'id': 0, 'au_type': 3, 'sequence_id': 1, 'AU_start_position': 13525}
{'id': 1, 'au_type': 3, 'sequence_id': 1, 'AU_start_position': 13587}
{'id': 2, 'au_type': 3, 'sequence_id': 1, 'AU_start_position': 14576}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if a cleaner solution exists to this problem, but a possible approach would be create another dictionary with keys being au_type and sequence_id. The values would be the id.

For example, let 'control' the this auxiliary dictionary. To the first input in your description, the code will verify if control[au_type][sequence_id] exists and what is the value for this id. The following steps would be increment the value o id and add AU_start_position to the set. The structure look like this:

```
{
  'au_type': {
      'sequence_id': {
           id: 0,
           AU_start_position: set()
       }
   }
}
```

Maybe this is an overkill, but probably works.